# Send file with skype4com in C#?

Tags: c#, skype, file-transfer, skype4com

Is it possible send file from C# application over Skype? I searched several topics but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the example? http://developer.skype.com/delphi-examples/a2astreams-pas

Comment: Are you familiar with Delphi...? this is a .pas file which is native to delphi

Comment: which library are you using to talk to Skype?

Answer (score 1):

either try to [open file dialog in attached skype client](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/Client-OpenFileTransferDialog-throws-exception/td-p/6983):

```
var skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
skype.Client.OpenFileTransferDialog("TargetUserHandle", "sourcePath");
```

or try to send the contents (1) [via Stream in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16193/Skype-Game-Infra) or (2) [via Stream in pas](http://developer.skype.com/delphi-examples/a2astreams-pas)

else you have to use (3) [Skype Kit SDK](http://developer.skype.com/skypekit/reference/cpp/tutorial_16_8cpp-example.html) - requires C/C++

[(1) and (3) worked for me]